# Why is Goldbach's conjecture hard to prove?

Tags: number-theory

Greettings. Why is goldbach's conjecture so hard to prove? I just want to know what are some of the obstacles mathematicians have met during the years.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/547858/why-goldbachs-conjecture-is-difficult-to-prove

Comment: IMO, we are lacking good theorems on the relation between the divisors of two numbers and those of their sum.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why Goldbach's conjecture is difficult to prove?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/547858/why-goldbachs-conjecture-is-difficult-to-prove)

Comment: In some way yes, it does. Thank you.

Comment: Here are my thoughts on the matter: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/955494/93271

Answer (score 3):

> Because we don't have any good generating function.

The miracle is that the ternary Goldbach conjecture can be proven to hold for $n$ large enough using the PNT and the circle method with the generating function $$(\sum_n \Lambda(n)e^{-nx})^3$$ where $\sum_n \Lambda(n)e^{-nx}$ is the inverse Mellin transform of $\Gamma(s)\frac{-\zeta'(s)}{\zeta(s)}$ and $\zeta(s)=\sum_n n^{-s}$ is among the simplest generating functions you can find.

There are a lot of texts discussing why this method fails for the binary Goldbach conjecture.

Comment: yeah you can look  at binary Goldbach in terms of Ternary Goldbach, just make one of the primes used 2.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the emails from random strangers about different versions of it don't help.

That being said, if looking for counterexamples you want to limit your search a lot,  there are a few ways ( 2,5 mod 6 equidistant 5 mod 6; 1,4 mod 6 equidistant to 1 mod 6;  3,0 mod 6 being unhelpfully equidistant to both) but it'll get tedious without a lot of cases ( above doesn't even cut cases by half for all inputs).

We can eliminate factors of $2n$ but, that doesn't help once we can't factor $n$

A rigorous proof won't include this most likely, as it only helps prove a finite set of cases.

Most related conjectures, are also unsolved, so we can't readily adapt a proof from them.

This leaves us with little options.